# How to add a background Image on JPanel without extending?

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jpanel

I want to add a background image on the panel. Most of the answers here says that you should use `JLabel` or extend a `JPanel` to use the `paintComponent`.

However in my project I used IntelliJ IDEA, with its GUI builder. Through the GUI builder I made my class extend through `JFrame`. Hence I can't use the extend panel method.

Here's how I have my class with its extending frame.

```
public class StoryFrame extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    public StoryFrame(){
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    }
}
```

I want to have `mainPanel` have its own background image.

I used a `GridLayout` so overlapping Swing Components also isn't an option.

Any other methods on how can we add a background image on a panel?

Comment: What's stopping you extending `mainPanel`?

Comment: *"Through the GUI builder I made my class extend through `JFrame`."* Good reason *not* to extend a frame number .. oh I've lost count. Extend a `JPanel` and set that as the content pane of the frame. GUI builders will allow code the programmer do that. If you cannot figure it out in the builder of InetlliJ, it might be a good reason *not* to use the GUI builder!

Comment: 1)  Stop using GUI Builders.  If you coded your GUI by hand, you would create a [drawing JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) by extending JPanel and placing your drawing JPanel inside your JFrame.  2) The only components that should be placed on a JFrame are JPanel and JScrollPane.  Other Swing components should be placed on one or more JPanels.

Comment: *Most of the answers here says that you should use JLabel or extend a JPanel to use the paintComponent.* - exactly, those are the two approaches. Understand the limitations/benefits of each approach and then choose which one you want to use and implement it in your code.

Comment: We mainly use GUI builders for simple projects like calculators and forms. Maybe extending JPanel is a better method than extending JFrame. Drawing the UI by hand may be better than GUI builders. Thanks everyone